# Application Error Dump Heap Memory - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

In my app, firstly I created an activity and passed fragments inside it. After I kept the app running for five minutes, my app goes to the first fragment and shows an ***error in the Log*** as:

> *"Too many open files"   log A/art:sart/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:76]*
>
> *Check failed: table_mem_map_.get() != nullptr ashmem_create_region failed for 'indirect ref table': Too many open files*

I thought this to be a memory problem, so I showed the Android profiler memory chart which gets very high when I receive data from the server.

Then, I added a library named as ***leakcanary library*** to show what's leak dump heap memory and I am getting this in my log.

> *Log : Could not dump heap, previous analysis still is in progress.*